# How to save redis om (HashModel) to a redis stream?

Tags: redis, redis-py

I can easily convert a redis-om Model to a string and then append the string to the stream.

```
r.xadd(name="myStream", fields= {'mydict': json.dumps(sensorSignal.json())})
```

What is the best/leanest practice to store that object in the stream in order for the consumers to have an easy way to parse back into the same type/model?

Answer (score 0):

Redis merely can take a key and a value as strings.

```
r.xadd(name=STREAM_KEY, fields= {'key': signal.pk, 'data': json.dumps(signal.json())})
```

When consuming the message one only needs to:

1. receive the message
2. fetch the key and value
3. decode the byte string
4. and load the decoded string into a dict (twice)
5. then finally instantiate the object of desire

Example

```
msg = r.xread( count=1, streams={STREAM_KEY:0} )        
logger.debug(f"RECEIVED MESSAGE FROM STREAM {msg[0][0]}")
for key, value in msg[0][1]:
  byte_string = value[b'data'] 
  decoded_data = byte_string.decode('utf8')
  deserialized = json.loads(decoded_data)
  # Call the load() twice to get rid of single quotes
  deserialized = json.loads(deserialized)
  # Convert into object
  ts = Signal(**deserialized)
  logger.debug(f"Read from the stream: {ts.algo_id}")
```